# Convert Jupyter notebook to PDF with nbconvert. Want the output to look exactly like the jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I use Jupyter notebook for Python in a project at school. I want to convert the notebook to a PDF file. I installed nbconvert and made it work. Only problem is that I want the pdf to look exactly like the notebook itself, ie include the borders around the input and output cells. When I used markdown in cells to comment my work the spacing also was wrong. Works great when I convert to html, but I need a pdf.

tl;dr: I want the PDF file to include the borders around the cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using template system of nbconvert.

There is already a template that you can use
https://github.com/t-makaro/nb_pdf_template

You should get something like this
[image]

### Installation

```
pip install nb_pdf_template
python -m nb_pdf_template.install
```

### Usage

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf filename.ipynb --template classic
```